# Autosys job history for last year

Tags: jobs, history, autosys

I need to find job history for a job for the last 6 months. I have tried autorep-j  -r -n but this just gives me data for last nth execution while I want data for all the days. Is there a way to do this through command line?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with that cmd to get that information.

I would query: $AUTOUSER/archive
Or look in DB if you have access there

Dave